# uninitialized constant ActiveRecord from exception_notification gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, mongoid

I Am using exception notifier like this in my rails 3.0.7-

```
gem 'exception_notification_rails3', :require => 'exception_notifier'
```

This application uses mongoid rather than ActiveRecord. But when I try to open rails c, it give following error -

```
Could not load SystemTimer >= v1.2.0. Falling back to timeout.rb. SystemTimer is STRONGLY recommended for timeouts in Ruby 1.8.7. See http://ph7spot.com/blog/system-timer-1-2-release for details.
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/exception_notification_rails3-1.2.0/lib/exception_notifier.rb:8:in `default_ignore_exceptions': uninitialized constant ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (NameError)
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/exception_notification_rails3-1.2.0/lib/exception_notifier.rb:7:in `tap'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/exception_notification_rails3-1.2.0/lib/exception_notifier.rb:7:in `default_ignore_exceptions'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/exception_notification_rails3-1.2.0/lib/exception_notifier.rb:30:in `initialize'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:33:in `new'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:33:in `build'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in `build'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:209:in `inject'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in `inject'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.7/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:79:in `build'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:162:in `build_middleware_stack'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:35
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
from /home/rtdp/workspace/bids/config/environment.rb:5
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.7/lib/rails/commands.rb:22
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6
```

I tried googling over this, but couldn't find anything related.
Thanks.

**UPDATE -** 
I just checked in /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/exception_notification_rails3-1.2.0/lib/exception_notifier.rb file. This file has code -

```
exceptions << ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound if defined? ActiveRecord
```

So commented this, and checked. Now the system works. So this means my active record is being declared somewhere. I reconfirmed this on console.

My application.rb file has this -

```
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

Now, what might be causing to include the ActiveRecord and then failing the Exception Notifier ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that some other gem was including the ActiveRecord as a dependency, and that was causing this to fail. I removed that gem and everything is fine now.

Answer (score 3):

People, http://github.com/rails/exception_notification is no longer the official exception_notification repo. See the note on the home page.

The official repo lies now on http://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification

If you do `gem install exception_notification` it will pull the gem from there.
This issue is already fixed there, if not please report the issue there.

Thanks!

Comment: ohh.. that explains few more general issues i faced for exception-notification with rails 3. thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

Erik Hollensbe [fixed this error](https://github.com/rails/exception_notification/pull/13) in his [personal fork](https://github.com/erikh/exception_notification) of exception_notifier.  His solution worked perfectly for me under Rails 3.0.9 and Ruby 1.9.2p180.